# Select all first record matching first unique word

Tags: mysql

I have the following data that looks similar to this:

```
id        property  position
========  ========  ========
1         Cool      Leader
2         Cool      Sponsor 1
3         Cool      Sponsor 2
4         Cool      Sponsor 3
5         Hot       Icon
6         Hot       Sponsor 2
7         Hot       Sponsor 3
```

I am attempting to write a query that returns rows of the unique position values but ignores the number after the position. So if Sponsor 1 exists then do not return rows where there is Sponsor 2 and Sponsor 3.

I expect the results to be:

```
id        property  position
========  ========  ========
1         Cool      Leader
2         Cool      Sponsor 1
5         Hot       Icon
6         Hot       Sponsor 2
```

How can I do this?

Comment: deleted - see what you're going after.

Comment: I think I would introduce a view on the data that would split position into position_name and position_index. This would allow you to select, order by position_index and do a unique on position_name. Or sthg along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

Using MySql

If you want to get the first occurrence of the string

```
SELECT property, position, SUBSTRING_INDEX(position, " ", 1) AS p2 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY p2, property;
```

Comment: This would work for a single property value but not for each property.

Comment: Will this work if the data is not already sorted? Say if Position 2 had a lower index value than Position 1 would Position 2 get returned?

Comment: Result will contain the first row found. If both have different property it wil return position 1 and 2 ... But if property the same it will return first one only according to their id order. If position 2 come first then it will be added instead